# ios - How to call a method from another class dynamically in a string?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm new to iPhone development,I want to call a method from another class in String

In LoginSuccess.m

```
- (void)Post:(NSString *)url AndSecondStr:(NSString *)postData AndThirdStr:(NSString *)contentType
```

In Register.m

```
LoginSuccess *loginViewInstance =  [[LoginSuccess alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginSuccess" bundle:nil];
[loginViewInstance Post:TxtEmailId AndSecondStr:TxtUserName AndThirdStr:serializeObject];
```

above one is executed,but I want to call that method in String like

```
NSString *result = [loginViewInstance Post:TxtEmailId AndSecondStr:TxtUserName AndThirdStr:serializeObject];
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

replace

```
- (void)Post:(NSString *)url AndSecondStr:(NSString *)postData AndThirdStr:(NSString *)contentType
```

with

```
- (NSString *)Post:(NSString *)url AndSecondStr:(NSString *)postData AndThirdStr:(NSString *)contentType
{
    NSString *str;
    str = someValue;
    return str;
}
```

Comment: On a side note @user2439531, remane your method `- (void)post:(NSString *)url andSecondStr:(NSString *)postData andThirdStr:(NSString *)contentType`. Using a CAPITAL LETTER on first the first letter in a variable is customary used for a class name. The Method Name Above Hurts My Eyes!

Answer (score 0):

your return type data is (void). please first replace it with NSString like:

```
(NSString *)Post:(NSString *)url AndSecondStr:(NSString *)postData AndThirdStr:(NSString *)contentType
{
//do something
}
```

then to call a method from another class you can do it 
like first add this code in Register.m.

```
#import "LoginSuccess.h"
```

and then call it like:

```
 LoginSuccess *Call_String = (LoginSuccess *)[LoginSuccess sharedApplication];

 NSString *result = [Call_String Post:TxtEmailId AndSecondStr:TxtUserName AndThirdStr:serializeObject];
```

hope your problem will be solved